Flask together with `POST` method doesn't yield any output from slovnik.seznam.cz
I have a flask structure as below:
root@k2:/mnt/c/Users/k2/myenvGPU32/myflaskapp# ls -lR . .: total 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  128 Jun 10 10:59 T.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  128 Jun 10 10:55 T.py~
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  926 Jun 10 20:17 app.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2969 Jun 10 19:57 app.py~ drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 20:17 templates

./templates: total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1283 Jun 10 20:17 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6104 Jun 10 19:58 index.html~

(but the button Translate doesn't produce any results)
with these files app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/translate', methods=['POST'])
def translate():
    term = request.json.get('term')
    url = f'https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/anglicky_cesky/{term}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        translation_div = soup.find('div', class_='entry')
        if translation_div:
            translation = translation_div.text.strip()
            return jsonify(success=True, translation=translation)
        else:
            return jsonify(success=False, error='Translation not found')
    return jsonify(success=False, error='Translation service unavailable')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

and
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Translate</title>
    <script>
        function translate() {
            const term = document.getElementById('translateTerm').value;
            fetch('/translate', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ term })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const translationDiv = document.getElementById('translation');
                if (data.success) {
                    translationDiv.textContent = data.translation;
                    translationDiv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    translationDiv.textContent = data.error;
                    translationDiv.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Translate</h1>
    <textarea id="translateTerm" placeholder="Enter term to translate"></textarea>
    <button onclick="translate()">Translate</button>
    <div id="translation" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
</html>

EDIT
C:\Users\k2\myenvGPU32\myflaskapp>python app.py

Serving Flask app 'app'
Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
Restarting with stat
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 134-339-617
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2024 20:44:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

EDIT2

EDIT3

EDIT4

EDIT5
A bit better but still the output doesn't go to browser but to the Anaconda prompt:

EDIT6 works quite good but not 100% perfect; 2nd snippet below is our target but I'm getting only first one


EDIT7: still unstructured

EDIT8: too many spaces in between rows

In the fetch part, try changing to:
...
    <script>
        function translate() {
            const term = document.getElementById('translateTerm').value;
            fetch('/translate', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({term: term})
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const translationDiv = document.getElementById('translation');
                if (data.success) {
                    translationDiv.innerHTML = data.translation;
                    translationDiv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    translationDiv.innerHTML= data.translation;
                    translationDiv.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
...

Python:
@app.route('/translate', methods=['POST'])
def translate():
    term = request.json.get('term')
    url = f'https://slovnik.seznam.cz/preklad/anglicky_cesky/{term}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        if response:
            translation = response.text
            return jsonify(success=True, translation=translation)
        else:
            return jsonify(success=False, error='Translation not found')
    return jsonify(success=False, error='Translation service unavailable')


Thank you for your help but have you tried your advice and are you sure it works ? For me it doesn't.

@user22758952 Do you have any errors or messages? What's the issue?

Please see my edit. That's what I'm getting with (C:\Users\k2\myenvGPU32) C:\Users\k2\myenvGPU32\myflaskapp>python app.py

@user22758952 try going to your browser and opening  http://127.0.0.1:5000

Yes there appear a textarea but the button translate doesn't do anything.

@user22758952 Can you inspect element and go to console to check the errors

@user22758952 please click on Konzole

@user22758952 This is good now! We're closer, since now it does show something. Let me think of a way to solve, this, a vote would help! :)

Great! I've upvoted, but still haven't accepted.

@user22758952 Can you try using another class like TranslatePage-wrapper so: translation_div = soup.find('div', class_='TranslatePage-wrapper')

Good. Could you give me a code sample together with file name where should I put it ?

Quite good, but not perfect: please see my EDIT6.

@user22758952 Check my edit, btw if I fixed your issue, please accept! Thanks a lot.

It really got improved, but it gives still a block of unstructured text rather than 2nd snippet in my EDIT6 :-( Please see my EDIT7.

I mean that it should have headers in color for every defined or main words and with ":" instead of "->". What is red may be green.

@user22758952 Try now my edit, btw this is not part of the question boundaries.

Good. But it doesn't parse  now, it gives something like this. Could you pelase fix it ?term překlad z angličtiny do češtiny – Seznam Slovník<meta name="theme-color" content="#cc000

@user22758952 Try my new edit

Dear U13, could you kindly have a look at this ?
